# How to skip web directory from URL in drupal 8 installation using htaccess after domain pointing?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal-8

I have installerd my drupal website and added inital configurations and pages using ip address , eg : http://111.22.33.88/web
My installation directory is as follow(I just added only basic files to know the structure)

```
public_html/
    vendors/
    web/
        core/
        sites/
        modules/
        themes/
        .htaccess
        index.php
```

Everything works fine but after pointing my ip address to my domain www.mysite.com. It works fine only if I add web subfolder in the path ie www.mysite.com/web

I dont need **web** folder in the url's. I have found one solution using .htaccess file and the code is as follows

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ web/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* web/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* web/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

I have added the above code by creating a new htaccess file in /public_html/.htaccess

Site and admin links works but some issues still exists , ie after login as admin, www.mysite.com/user/login, site get logged in but shows a white page of error as follows
**"Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it."**

Can someone help to fix this, I think I have missed something in my newly created .htaccess file or some additional settings to  eliminate web directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate the issue by adding the following in settings.php

```
if (isset($GLOBALS['request']) and
'/web/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME')) {
$GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I approached it differently without code. My webhost (inmotion) lets you provide the root folder and in my case I was trying to point the domain name to a subfolder. So I pointed the domain name to /public_html/subfolder/web instead of just /public_html/subfolder. And it worked.